# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long jedis

Tags: java, jedis

I am using Amazon ElastiCach for Redis to store some items. In one method I am calling redis 3 or 4 times with one jedis client getted from JedisPool. After last call to redis both JedisPool and Jedis are closed. I call this method a 50 time in a minute. It just stops working in some point with messages:
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Shoud I make it work one call to redis - one Jedis from JedisPool?

Here is my code:

```
AmazonElastiCacheClient client = new AmazonElastiCacheClient(awsElastiCashCredentials);
        Region elastiCachRegion = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(amazonProps.getElastiCachRegion()));
        client.setRegion(elastiCachRegion);

        DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();
        dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);

        DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = client.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);

        JedisPool pool = null;
        List<CacheCluster> cacheClusters = clusterResult.getCacheClusters();
        for (CacheCluster cacheCluster : cacheClusters) {
            if (cacheCluster.getCacheClusterId().equals("001")) {
                for (CacheNode cacheNode : cacheCluster.getCacheNodes()) {
                    String addr = cacheNode.getEndpoint().getAddress();
                    int port = cacheNode.getEndpoint().getPort();

                    try {
                        pool = new JedisPool(addr, port);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and method:

```
try (JedisPool pool = amazonElastiCacheService.connectToCachCluster()) {
                try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {

                    fileEmail(jedis);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: share the complete error log/message

Comment: **java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long** and **java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List**

Comment: not 1 line log, share **complete** log atleast 10 lines of error log

Comment: That is all error that I get

Comment: Is it ok to tag redis on this completely unrelated question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are assigning List(`ArrayList`)of Object value to Long object.
See `line`#/`Class` , `method` and modify.
Or check all the **`Long`** value assignments in your code, some where u r setting n `ArrayList` object to it.

e.g.

```
Long value;
List<?> myList = new ArrayList<?>();
value = myList ;
```

I dint find any problem from the code you shared.